# Can't connect to a computer on network by name but can do by ip

Tags: windows-xp, networking, window

I using `windows Xp` os on a `Windows 2003` network. I get error when connect to a computer by name and can by ip. 
My ip is `192.168.20.92` and another's computer ip is `192.168.23.60`

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am learning english language.)

**Edited**

I want open share folders of `192.168.23.60` by explorer but when try open its share by name (as `\\sebastian` in address bar of explorer), getting error:

```
\\sebastian is not accessible. you may not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permission.

The server's clock is not synchronized with the primary domain controller's clock.
```

but when I open by ip (as `\\192.168.23.60` in address bar of explorer) all done fine.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to (i.e. how you want to connect) and what kind of error your receive.

Comment: What is the out put of ' net time'?

Comment: @Luke I don't understand your means,please explain more.

Comment: @MJM Open the Command Prompt and type `NET TIME` and press Enter. What is the output?

Comment: System error 52 has occurred.
@Luke oh,I understand. I run `Net Time` command and get following result:`You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network.Go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again.`

Comment: @Luke I'm sorry for replying late and sorry for bad format at previews comment. I test your suggestion and run `Net time` command and get following result:`System error 52 has occurred. You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. Go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again.`

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the system, as it might be used in the network. In the default gateway of the XP machine, give the server IP which is connected on the network. Reboot the XP machine.

Ping the local system with the server, to check the connectivity. Try to connect it to the network.

Answer (score 0):

These are on different subnets so it could be down to firewall rules/policies. Or it could be down to a missing dns entry for 192.168.23.60. Try pinging with the fqdn and then pinging another pc on the 23 subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a DNS problem. More info would be needed to troubleshoot effectively.
Does your W2003 Server act as a DNS server?
If so can you ping the pc by name from the server?
Do the PC's use the server for DNS?

Comment: Yes,I can ping by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can `ping sebastian` then DNS works. Some parts of Windows like `net use \\sebastian` (and presumably Explorer too) resolve names not via DNS but WINS a.k.a NetBios Names.

Perhaps a misconfigured WINS is the source of your problem. Do you have the same problem with other clients on the network?
Microsoft has troubleshooting guides for clients and servers:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739183(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It can be the wrong date or time.

I Just had this problem. Please check the date and time.  It won´t allow you to access the server if the date/time is different of the client machine.